# Build n-instances with different attributes of the same component

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I have a component that has as an attribute a string list. I would like to create n-instances of that component, with different string lists inside and render them. How can I do?

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>


      <ng-template let-art let-last="last" ngFor [ngForOf]="categories">
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/category/', art.name]"> {{art.name}} </a>

      </ng-template>



      <a mat-fab color="accent" class="mat-fab-bottom-right fixed z-3" (click)="prueba()">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
      </a>

    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div style="height: 88vh;">

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, Router, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category/category.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  routes: Routes = AppRoutingModule.getRoutes();
  categories : Array<CategoryComponent>;
  title = 'app works!';

  i: number;

  constructor(private router: Router){
    this.i = 11;
    console.log(this.routes);
    this.categories = new Array();

  }

  prueba(){

    var a : CategoryComponent = new CategoryComponent();

    a.setName(this.i.toString())

    this.i++;
    this.categories.push(a);


  }

  navegar(ruta:string){
    this.router.navigate([ruta]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us some of your code? I'm getting a feeling this has to do with `*ngFor`, but a little piece of code could help.

Comment: @Carlos if you know javascript and have gone throungh very basic example of angular, this should not be a problem. You first need to learn Angular instead of solving problems

Comment: @Amit B. With the prueva method I can only dynamically add categories to the sidenav items and configure their route in the html. The idea is that every time i click on one of those categories, i can see the name...

Comment: @CarlosQuiñones the code looks fine to me, can you maybe upload your code to StackBlitz so we could look at it with more context?

Comment: use a `@Input` to change some values of your component? https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties